# Netbeans showing an error which successfully builds and works

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

I think I found an annoying bug (if not then someone explain please) in NetBeans 8.1 where C++11 shows an error and C++04 - I believe - not.

```
OtherClass* getOtherInstance(Coordiantes c) { return this->array[c.x][c.y] }
instance.getOtherInstance(Coordinates(0,0))->sayHello();
```

This code works, but when I used C++11's convenient features (which I use quite often) inside the parameters of the method, NB showed an error which surprisingly **builds fine**. So it looks like this:

```
instance.getOtherInstance({0,0})->sayHello(); // Error: unable to resolve identifier sayHello.
```

I know the problem is not big yet it is quite annoying to me having to write Coordinates(0,0) every time. Is there any way I could get rid of the error?

Comment: Have you tried `Reparsing Project`  ?

Comment: Yes, I did try reparsing the project. No result.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime Netbeans gives me an error, but code compiles fine, I successfully correct it by erasing the MPLABX cache directory. I use Mac, but very likely it doesn't matter.

In my case, the 'var' cache directory is located at:

```
/Users/USER_NAME/Library/Caches/mplab_ide/dev/v3.35/var
```

(replace USER_NAME with your user name)

Let us know if it worked, or you find another solution.